# Javascript: Cross fading text between text changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying all sorts of things, but being new with javascript and jquery I can't seem to get something as trivial as this working. My code below is working, but I would like it to smoothly crossfade between changes.

```
var texts = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"];
var count = 0;
function addText() {
    $("#user").text(texts[count]).fadeOut();
    $("#user").text(texts[count]).fadeIn();
    count < 4 ? count++ : count = 0;
}
setInterval(addText, 500);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var texts = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"];
var count = 0;
function addText() {
    $("#user").text(texts[count]).fadeOut().delay(1).fadeIn();
    count < 4 ? count++ : count = 0;
}
setInterval(addText, 500);
```

**Update:**

An improved function which takes serveral hints from @adricadar

```
var texts = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"];
var count = 0;
var interval = 2000;

function addText() {
    $("#user").fadeTo(interval/2 -1, 0.01, function(){
       // this callback runs when fadeOut is finished
       // so that the text change is "invisible"
       $(this).text(texts[count]); 
    }).delay(1).fadeTo(interval/2, 1);
    // Note that arrays are zero indexed so "Four" would blink twice. 
    count < texts.length ? count++ : count = 0; 
}
setInterval(addText, interval);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/736vb5tk/1/

Comment: This works great! I guess I was missing the delay, but how can I have it done so that the text above and below it doesn't flicker as it jumps up and down?

Comment: Make sure they have the CSS property `display: none`.

Comment: What you where missing is that when you select an element twice and add an animation the animations run at the same time. When you chain the animations and add delay then it runs synchronously (one after the other).

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant by the "the text above and below it doesn't flicker". What you can do is make sure that `#user` has a set height and I also changed the animation to use fade

Answer (score 2):

Here, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/736vb5tk/1/), i attached a link with a demo based on your code.

```
var texts = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"];
var count = 0;
var interval = 2000;
function addText() {
    $("#user").text(texts[count]).fadeOut(interval / 2);
    $("#user").text(texts[count]).fadeIn(interval / 2);
    count < 4 ? count++ : count = 0;
}
setInterval(addText, interval);
```

Comment: Nice but it looks like the text change occurs when its full opacity. I updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/736vb5tk/1/

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use a callback for the `fadeOut` method.

```
$("#user").text(texts[count])
  .fadeOut( interval/2,
            function(){$("#user").text(texts[count]).fadeIn(interval/2);} );
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/qdzg0rvf/)